# Making HTTPS requests using ESP8266 AT commands

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, http, espressif

I am trying to make HTTPS GET/POST requests to the following server using AT commands.

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","54.166.71.140 ",443
```

I get errors when i use port 443 but on port 80 the requests are successful.

How can i get around this issue ? what could be potential solutions ?

Comment: read the reference, please

Comment: are you referring to this docuement ?  https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/AT_Command_Set/TCP-IP_AT_Commands.html

Comment: it depends. that is for AT 2.1. for AT 1.7 this https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTTPS requires that you make an SSL connection not a TCP connection.  To do that you need to use

```
AT+CIPSTART="SSL","54.166.71.140 ",443
```

You also need to configure SSL itself.

However the SSL support is not great and struggles with some sites (no SNI support by all accounts).

So you're better off programming the ESP8266 directly with your own sketch to make any HTTPS requests and process the data for you.

Comment: How do i configure the SSL, is there any reference ?

Comment: From the examples I've seen it looks like it's just setting the SSL buffer size. There's configuration commands but I haven't seen them being used.

Comment: That solved it :) the buffer size was 2048 by default